# Показывать элементы, содержащие определенные слова

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<div class="menu-navigation-lessons">
    <a class="nav-lessons" href="#">Все</a>
    <a class="nav-lessons" href="#">Дизайн</a>
    <a class="nav-lessons" href="#">Новости</a>
</div>
<div class="article">
<div class="title_article">
    <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
    <div class="description">
        <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex mollitia dolores dignissimos velit
            voluptas.
            Hic perspiciatis dolorum ullam delectus voluptatibus atque nobis aspernatur! Consequatur quo eos
            delectus!
            Laboriosam, reprehenderit vel. </p>
        <p class="category"> <span>category</span>: JavaScript </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <div class="title_article">
    <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
    <p class="category"> <span>category</span>: jQuery </p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="article">
    <div class="title_article">
        <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
        <p class="category"> <span>category</span>: Css </p>
</div>
</div>
```

У меня есть статьи и у них есть категории. И есть кнопки, отвечающие за определенные категории (например: новости). Мне надо, чтобы по клику показывались те статьи, у которых есть определенная категория (например кнопка с категорией новости, отвечает за статьи с новостями). Если я нажимаю на кнопку с категорией новости, то статьи с категорией программирования и дизайна скрываются. И так с категорией программирования и дизайна. Пытался делать через `:contains`, `:has`, `:not`, `indexOf`, но ничего не помогло.

Comment: Прошу вас добавить написанный вами JS код, который по вашему мнению не работает или работает не так как нужно.

Comment: У вас сделано 3 ссылки (тег `а`) которые переведут вас на нужную страницу (ту что указана в атрибуте `href`) Там можете прописать какие статьи вы хотите видеть. Вообще по хорошему вопрос надо дополнить, описать более подробно.

Comment: @rafnsvartr нет, смотри я не хочу каждый раз тратить время на добавление статьи в каждую категрию, я хочу, чтоб это все сделал скрипт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Находит текст категорию содержащуююся в `.category` , сравнивает значение с текстом ссылки.

```js
$('.menu-navigation-lessons a').not(":contains('Все')").on('click',function(){
var text = $(this).text();
$('.article').hide();
$(`.article .category:contains(${text})`).closest('.article').show()
})

$('.menu-navigation-lessons a:contains("Все")').on('click',function(){
$('.article').show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-navigation-lessons">
    <a class="nav-lessons" href="#">Все</a>
    <a class="nav-lessons" href="#">Дизайн</a>
    <a class="nav-lessons" href="#">Новости</a>
</div>
<div class="article">
<div class="title_article">
    <h2>Дизайн</h2>
    <div class="description">
        <p> Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex mollitia dolores dignissimos velit
            voluptas.
            Hic perspiciatis dolorum ullam delectus voluptatibus atque nobis aspernatur! Consequatur quo eos
            delectus!
            Laboriosam, reprehenderit vel. </p>
        <p class="category"> <span>category</span>: Дизайн </p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <div class="title_article">
    <h2>Новости</h2>
    <p class="category"> <span>category</span>: Новости </p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="article">
    <div class="title_article">
        <h2>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h2>
        <p class="category"> <span>category</span>: Css </p>
</div>
</div>
```